# AppWidget Configuration Activity launches despite configuration_optional

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

When a user adds an app widget, it should right away display predefined data, and only in case the user wants to configure the widget later, they would long press, and select settings to launch the configuration activity.

This is working as expected on Pixel emulators, but not working on a Samsung device.

My AppWidgetProvider xml has:

```
android:configure="com.domain.appname.ActivityWidgetConfigure"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"
android:widgetFeatures="reconfigurable|configuration_optional"
```

where `configuration_optional` should provide the option to skip configuration on first time adding a widget.

Is there some nuance on enabling this functionality on the different manufactures devices?